# What is the best way to group and then sort an array of strings by their value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings like this, however I'm not sure of how to group them, and then sort them. Inititially I used this function group them by unique values, however not sure how to then sort them. I was also wondering if there's a way to do it with a single function. I've attached what the function returns in it's current state.

```
[
  60777b59b85d3d0eb2f1a13b,
  60777aeeb85d3d0eb2f1a12e,
  60777bacb85d3d0eb2f1a147,
  60778c56f06d4e1b63759fd4,
  60778c56f06d4e1b63759fd4,
  60777486b85d3d0eb2f1a0d5,
  607778adb85d3d0eb2f1a0f6,
  60777ad3b85d3d0eb2f1a12a,
  60777842b85d3d0eb2f1a0e9,
  60777ad3b85d3d0eb2f1a12a,
  60777bacb85d3d0eb2f1a147,
  60777842b85d3d0eb2f1a0e9,
  60777a56b85d3d0eb2f1a11d
]

const countUnique = arr => {
          const counts = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             counts[arr[i]] = 1 + (counts[arr[i]] || 0);
          };
          return counts;
       };
```

[image]

Comment: Your question has an invalid array. None of those elements are strings. Also _"'m not sure of how to group them, and then sort them"_: how do you want to group and sort them. That's missing from your question.

Comment: Ah sorry Andy, so I just want to sort them by their count. So in this example, all of the strings with a count of 2, should be at the top.

Comment: But you are making an object finally. Are you looking to get an array in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countUnique = arr => {
  const counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counts[arr[i]] = 1 + (counts[arr[i]] || 0);
  };
  return Object.entries(counts).sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 1).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
};
```